# Does Visual Studio 2013 CTP support in-class static const initializers for non-integral types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

When using g++ (and clang++ last time I checked) I can write this in a header and expect it to work:

```
struct test
{
    static constexpr float MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42.0f;
};
```

However Visual Studio 2013 CTP requires this (and it compiles without warning or error):

```
struct test
{
    static const float MEANING_OF_LIFE;
};
const float test::MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42.0f; // <- In the header, not a .cpp file.
```

Is this a deficiency of Visual Studio or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: constexpr is very different from const. If you were to use "const" in g++/clang they should not allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second case is wrong: it would need to be

```
struct test
{
    static const float MEANING_OF_LIFE;
};

const float test::MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42.0f; // In an implementation file
```

The actual definition will need to go in an implementation (.cpp) file, not in a header, or else you'll get an ODR violation.

The first case is valid C++11, but I guess Visual Studio doesn't support it yet. (It probably will work if you use an integral type instead of `float`, as that was also permitted in C++98.)

Comment: "The actual definition will need to go in an implementation (.cpp) file, not in a header". **Need to** or **should**? It does work as I've posted it; compiles with no warnings or errors.

Comment: @DrTwox If you're only including the header in one .cpp file, you'll get away with it. But if you include it in more than one .cpp file then it will compile okay, but fail to link because of duplicate `test::MEANING_OF_LIFE` symbols. (Unless your `test` class is templated of course, but that's a different matter.)